# Flutter Error: A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to read from `shared preferences` but i got stuck. I've got this error and I don't know how to deal with it:
`A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'`

My code looks like this:

```
onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (_getPref()) {       //here occurs the error
            _stateColor = _disableColor;
            _setPref(false);
          } else {
            _stateColor = _enableColor;
            _setPref(true);
          }
        });
      },
```

And the method:

```
Future<bool> _getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool value = prefs.getBool(widget.myIndex) ?? false;
    return value;
  }
```

I would by grateful if someone would help me!

Comment: The if condition expects a bool value, but _getPref is a Future<bool>,  make the setState body async and if(await _getPref)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to `await` the `_getPref()` function because it returns a future `Future<bool>`

```dart
onTap: () async {
    if (await _getPref()) {       //here occurs the error
      _stateColor = _disableColor;
      _setPref(false);
    } else {
      _stateColor = _enableColor;
      _setPref(true);
    }
    setState(() {});
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, you can do it.

1. Use `async-await`:

   ```dart
   void func() async {
     bool value = await _getPref();
     setState(() {
       _value = value;
     });
   }
   ```
2. Use `then`

   ```dart
   void func() {
     _getPref().then((value) {
       setState(() {
         _value = value;
       });
     });
   }
   ```